# Navigation Drawer Layout overlapping with main layout

Tags: android

How do I get my main layout to simply line up directly underneath my DrawerLayout?  My main layout is listed below and is mainly made up of listviews.  Right now everything is overlapping.  So the below first shows my DrawerLayout.  After closing of DrawerLayout my main activity is listed.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>


    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name=“com.example.my.app.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>





<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent”
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_empty_list_cars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/view1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_cars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem is `drawer layout` overlapping the `linear layout` below. Use

```
android: layout_below="@id/drawer_layout"
```

In your `linear layout`. That will linearly arrange both layouts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the DrawerLayout correctly, it has to be the only root / parent view of your entire layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> 

      /*other nested child views */

      <fragment
      android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
      ... 
      />    

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, to prevent the over lapping, ensure that you have two direct child views as per design guideline at
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

"To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of match_parent . Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the
layout_gravity appropriately."

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if your are looking for a sliding panel like the new gmail app
but if yes you can refer yourself [Sliding Pane Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) and this very awesome [tutorial](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html).

hope it helps, happy codings.